# How to swap children in a tree in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree

I'm fairly new to Haskell. What I'm trying to do is swap the order of the children in a tree. I'm not sure how to make my code swap the two children if they are both integers. Thanks!

```
# For example:
# If t1 = (* (+ 20 1) (- 10 8))
# Then when I call 'swap t1' I should get (* (- 8 10) (+ 1 20)) but I get (* (- 10 8) (+ 20 1))

#Here is my code:
data Tree =
     TInt Integer
   | TOp String Tree Tree

t1 = TOp "*" (TOp "+" (TInt 20) (TInt 1))
             (TOp "-" (TInt 10) (TInt 8))

swap :: Tree -> Tree
swap (TInt i) = TInt i
swap (TOp s first second) = TOp s second first
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, but you're not going all the way. The second line of `swap` swaps the *immediate* children of the top-level tree (from `first second` to `second first`), but if `first` and/or `second` have further children under them, those children will remain unswapped, because you're not modifying either `first` or `second` in any way.

So how do you swap all the children of `first` and `second`, I wonder? Well, both of them are of type `Tree`... If only there was a function that takes a `Tree`, swaps its children, and returns another `Tree`... Oh, wait! That's our `swap` function! Why don't we use it to swap all the children of `first` and `second`?

```
swap (TOp s first second) = TOp s (swap second) (swap first)
```